# file upload progress jumping to 100% before upload

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am not able to do progress percentage to this file upload function. I googled it a lot i couldn't find solution

Here is my code:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 10, progress[0], false);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "changed");
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String upLoadServerUri = upurl;
    String fileName = urls[0];
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    int sentBytes = 0;
    long fileSize = sourceFile.length();

     try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(urls[0]));

            URL url = new URL(upurl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",     "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(     connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[]\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.v("Size",bytesAvailable+"");

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                // Update progress dialog
                sentBytes += bytesRead;
                publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize));

                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                Log.v("Available",bytesAvailable+"");

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,     maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,      bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            Scanner s = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
            final String response = s.next();

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode       = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                         Toast.makeText(BabupMain.this, "server say :" + response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Toast.makeText(BabupMain.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
             }

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(BabupMain.this, "Error 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (final Exception e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(BabupMain.this, "Error 2 "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        //publishProgress();

        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say really, but consider changing

```
publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize))
```

To

```
double progress = (double)sentBytes / fileSize;
publishProgress((int)progress);
```

---

**EDIT**

I would change this:

```
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{

      // Update progress dialog
    sentBytes += bytesRead;
    publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize));

    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    Log.v("Available",bytesAvailable+"");



    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,     maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,      bufferSize);
}
```

To

buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];

```
while (true)
{
    int bytesToRead = Math.min(maxBufferSize, fileInputStream.available());

    // Break if complete
    if(bytesToRead == 0){ break; }

    // Read bytes
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

    // Write bytes
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    // Update progress dialog
    sentBytes += bytesRead;

    // Publish progress
    double progress = (double)sentBytes / fileSize;
    publishProgress((int)progress);
}
```

If you're having issues with this, I'd abandon the `FileInputStream.available()` approach, get the total number of bytes from [`File.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) and break out of the loop when `bytesRead >= File.length()`.

Comment: OH please guys ;) you are the expert here should i change the upload function ?

Comment: thank you for you time bro i tried them both , but the notification becomes sticky and the phone freezing , i give up :D

Answer (score 0):

only having a short look at it...

1. sentBytes * 100 / fileSize

   int sentBytes = 0;
   long fileSize = sourceFile.length();

   be aware calculating with int and long will turncate at decimal point. maybe cast to double.
2. second which I can't see because of missing code but the comment screems for it

   > but the notification becomes sticky and the phone freezing

   you are using publishProgress() in a background thread(doInBackground()), I hop you don't try to touch GUI whilst in background thread

   you could use a Handler() to post a Runnable which will be used by gui thread

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and nice solution here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html in the section "Posting Content":

Add:

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

Just after:

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```