# Progress bar resets itself?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

When I upload files over 5MB, the progress bar resets itself when it reaches 4% and start from 0 every 10 sec. But, for files under 5MB, the progress bar works fine and reaches 100%

Is this because of `maxBufferSize`? The server max post size is 512MB and every thing else is unlimited, so the problem must be from my code but I'm not sure where.

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

     //update Dialog box progress   
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]); 
        if ( nofti_appended )
        {       
         //update Notification progress
          mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
        }
}


protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {    
            String upLoadServerUri = upApi.uploadUrl;
            String fileName = this.file_path;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize =  1*1024*1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
            int sentBytes = 0;
            long fileSize = sourceFile.length();

             try
                {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                    // Enable POST method
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",     "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(     connection.getOutputStream() );
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[]\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    Log.v("Size",bytesAvailable+"");

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


                    // Read file
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {

                        if(isCancelled()){

                            break;
                        }

                        sentBytes += bytesRead;
                        publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize));

                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,     maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,      bufferSize);
                    }


                   if(isCancelled()){

                        return "faild";
                    }

                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                     Scanner s;
                     s = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
                     s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
                     final String response = s.next();

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    int serverResponseCode       = connection.getResponseCode();

                    fileInputStream.close();
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();

                    if(serverResponseCode == 200)
                     {
                        return response;
                     }


                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                } catch (final Exception e) {

                }

            return "faild";
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to trim this to remove all of the extra code that has nothing to do with the actual upload process. The content type and all of the other stuff isn't needed, and makes your actual question harder to answer. Please [edit your question] to remove everything except the code relevant to the question you're asking here, so we can try and help you find a solution. Thanks. :-)

Comment: what about now ? is my question hard to understand ! all i need to know why the progress bar reset to 0 when its reach the 4% for large files

Comment: publishProgress((int)(sentBytes * 100 / fileSize)); that line has to be getting set to 0 if your progressbar is resetting.  Why are you multiplying sentBytes * 100?

Comment: someone advised me to do it at this thread , but wait is this why the progress bar reset to 0 ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748207/file-upload-progress-jumping-to-100-before-upload/15748263?noredirect=1#15748263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually have two problems with your progress calculation:

First, your logic is not quite right. It should be (see the next paragraph for the reason why):

```
(sentBytes / fileSize) * 100
```

The second problem, though, is that you're using `int` values, but trying to do a floating point calculation. (Percentage is `0.01` - `1.00`, and then it's multiplied by `100` to turn it into `1%` - `100%`.) You need to do the calculation as floating point, and then cast the final value to integer.

Try something like

```
publishProgress((int)(((sentBytes * 1.0) / fileSize) * 100)));
```

That's getting to be a lot of `()` pairs, though. It would be better to declare a separate `float` or `double` variable, and use it instead:

```
percentDone = (sentBytes * 1.0) / fileSize * 100;
publishProgress((int)percentDone);
```